# Will my speeding ticket in Arizona be enforced abroad?

Tags: speeding

Good evening,

as a tourist from outside the U.S., I got pulled over for speeding near Page, AZ (outside urbanized area) today. I went 80 instead of 65. My bad. The officer gave me a ticket and asked me to call the court in Page to negotiate and pay my fine, credit cards would be acceptable. Since I am not familiar with this stuff here in the U.S., may I ask anybody here in this forum for advise on how to handle this? Should I just ignore it and leave the country (which is scheduled for next week)? How much is the fine (the officer said it depends on various aspects and I should negotiate this with the court)? What happens if I ignore it - will I be hindered from re-entering the US in the future? I don't mean to trick the system and welch on my fine, but I'd still like to know my options in order not to diminish my legal status. Thanks a lot for your advise.

Best, Jay

Comment: Pay the fine. Not knowing from where, cannot say if it will be inforced in 'somewhere outside the US'. Yes, there are reports that such non compliance with the law is passed on and could effect future entries.

Comment: According to [this website](https://www.ncourt.com/x-press/x-onlinepayments.aspx?juris=1FC7A89A-64C2-446D-A7BB-E619449E660F), somewhere between $190 and $300 depending on whether you were 15 mph over or 16 (or more) over.

Answer (score 2):

### Will it be enforced abroad? Probably not. Will it have negative consequences if you return to the United States? [Probably](https://www.aztriallawyer.com/blog/2016/07/what-happens-if-i-dont-pay-a-traffic-ticket/).

Given the relatively small amount of the fine, it is not likely to be worth the county's time, money and effort to find you and pursue the debt in your country.

However, it is possible that if the fine remains unpaid a warrant may be issued for your arrest. This may prevent you from getting a visa or participation in the visa-waiver program as applicable. Even if you do get in, if you come to the attention of the police, the warrant will flash up on their computer and you will be arrested, jailed and extradited to Arizona all at your expense.

Basically, if you ever want to return to the US, pay the fine.

Comment: Thank you all! Any idea as to how much the fine will be? When I talk to the court, what would be a smart move to say, what shouldn't I say? I am from Germany, BTW. Thanks for your advise!

Comment: @Jay, just give them the ticket number and they will tell you the cost. There is nothing in the transaction that would put you at risk.  You will talk to a clerk.